# Cannot set headers of an Iron framework Response

Tags: rust, iron

I am looking to set the headers of a Iron `Response` with the following code:

```
extern crate iron;  // 0.3.0
extern crate hyper; // 0.8.1

use iron::prelude::*;
use iron::status;

use hyper::header::{Headers, ContentType};
use hyper::mime::{Mime, TopLevel, SubLevel};

use std::error::Error;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    fn hello_world(_: &mut Request) -> IronResult<Response> {
        let mut headers = Headers::new();
        let string = getFileAsString("./public/index.html");

        headers.set(
            ContentType(Mime(TopLevel::Text, SubLevel::Html, vec![]))
        );

        Ok(Response::with((status::Ok, string, headers)))
    }

    Iron::new(hello_world).http("localhost:3000").unwrap();
    println!("On 3000");
}

fn getFileAsString(fileStr: &str) -> String {
    let path = Path::new(fileStr);
    let display = path.display();
    let mut fileContents = String::new();

    let mut file = match File::open(&path) {
        Err(why) => panic!("couldn't open {}: {}", display, Error::description(&why)),
        Ok(file) => file,
    };

    match file.read_to_string(&mut fileContents) {
        Err(why) => panic!("couldn't read {}: {}", display, Error::description(&why)),
        Ok(_) => fileContents
    }    
}
```

However I get the error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `iron::Headers: iron::modifier::Modifier<iron::Response>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:24:12
   |
24 |         Ok(Response::with((status::Ok, string, headers)))
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `iron::modifier::Modifier<iron::Response>` is not implemented for `iron::Headers`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `iron::modifier::Modifier<iron::Response>` for `(hyper::status::StatusCode, std::string::String, iron::Headers)`
   = note: required by `iron::Response::with`
```

Why am I not able to pass headers into this tuple to be modified by the `Request` builder?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can modify the headers on the `Response` object:

```
fn hello_world(_: &mut Request) -> IronResult<Response> {
    let string = get_file_as_string("./public/index.html");
    let mut resp = Response::with((status::Ok, string));
    resp.headers.set(ContentType(Mime(TopLevel::Text, SubLevel::Html, vec![])));
    Ok(resp)
}
```

---

To figure out the original error, let's check the error message:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `iron::Headers: iron::modifier::Modifier<iron::Response>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:24:12
   |
24 |         Ok(Response::with((status::Ok, string, headers)))
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `iron::modifier::Modifier<iron::Response>` is not implemented for `iron::Headers`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `iron::modifier::Modifier<iron::Response>` for `(hyper::status::StatusCode, std::string::String, iron::Headers)`
   = note: required by `iron::Response::with`
```

The first line tells us the immediate issue: `iron::Headers` does not implement the trait `iron::modifier::Modifier<iron::Response>`. If we check the [documentation for `Headers`](https://docs.rs/iron/0.3.1/iron/struct.Headers.html), we can see under the *Trait Implementations* section that it indeed does not implement `Modifier`.

We can then look at the problem from the other end: what *does* implement `Modifier`? The docs for `Modifier`, when built in conjunction with Iron, answer that question. One thing we can see is:

```
impl<H> Modifier<Response> for Header<H>
where
    H: Header + HeaderFormat,
```

This leads to an alternate possibility:

```
use iron::modifiers::Header;

fn hello_world(_: &mut Request) -> IronResult<Response> {
    let string = get_file_as_string("./public/index.html");
    let content_type = Header(ContentType(Mime(TopLevel::Text, SubLevel::Html, vec![])));
    Ok(Response::with((status::Ok, string, content_type)))
}
```

And if we look at [the implementation of `Modifier` for `Header`](https://github.com/iron/iron/blob/0.3.0/src/modifiers.rs#L162-L170):

```
fn modify(self, res: &mut Response) {
    res.headers.set(self.0);
}
```

It just sets the headers as we did above.

---

FYI, Rust style is `snake_case` for variables and methods and `Error::description(&why)` is normally written `why.description()`.

Comment: Thanks, could you explain why I cannot pass headers into the tuple as I understand Response::with accepts a tuple of modifiers for the response object?

Comment: @JacobClark ah yes, I forgot the important part of the answer!

Comment: excellent, thank you! Possibly out of the scope now, but how is the tuple applied? I would normally expect to see a form each iterating through each modifier, but in the Iron modifier source I do not see this, can you point me to where/how each modifier in a tuple is applied?